# What is the meaning of "Bulk Strip"?

Tags: piston-engine

What does the following mean and what ramifications does it have when purchasing an aircraft?

> term R/H-1958 HOURS SMOH@26/02/1988   - BULK STRIP 27/03/1998  ENGINE
>   1472 SMOH

Does it mean the engine will be at its lide use and has to be replaced with another or am I correct that they replaced some parts to extend the time based on condition and will require a full overhaul 528 hors?

Comment: [Related question about overhaul terminology](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/7684/1696)

Answer (score 3):

A *bulk strip* may be an Australian term, e.g. [this airworthiness bulletin](https://www.casa.gov.au/sites/g/files/net351/f/_assets/main/airworth/awb/85/005.pdf) and [this engine shop](http://www.bilyaragroup.com.au/EnginesMaintenance/BilyaraBlueSealEngines/EngineRepairsInspections/tabid/77/Default.aspx). I'd never heard of it before, but looking at those sites it seems to be something like a limited overhaul. The AB and the engine shop both list the steps and they're more or less the same: disassemble the engine, inspect all parts, replace any parts that need replacement, reassemble and test the engine.

I'm not an expert on maintenance by any means, but it looks to me like the difference between a bulk strip and a full overhaul is that the bulk strip is precautionary or diagnostic, as suggested by the machine shop site:

> Not all engines need a full overhaul. You may have had a prop-strike,
>   or your LAME may have identified metal in the filter or a crack in the
>   crankcase. The pilot may have noticed unusual running of the engine.
>
> We can ‘bulk-strip’ your engine for a full diagnosis and provide you
>   with a report of your engine’s health:

Looking at it another way, an overhaul *will* replace a lot of parts whether they need it or not; a bulk strip *may* replace parts if they're worn or broken.

Comment: This is consistent with this [question on PPRuNE](http://www.pprune.org/pacific-general-aviation-questions/140890-cost-engine-bulk-strip.html).